# find sorting index per row of a 2D matrix in MatLab and populate a new matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing, populate

I have a challenge to order my matrix. The provided functions like `sortrows` work in the opposite way...

Take this 2D matrix

```
M =
     40    45    68
     50    65    58
     60    55    48
     57    67    44    
                      ,
```

The objective is to find matrix `O` that indicates the sorting index (rank) per row, i.e.:

```
O =

     1     2     3
     1     3     2
     3     2     1
     2     3     1
                       .
```

So for the second row `50` is the smallest element (1), `65` the largest (3), and `58` is the second largest (2), therefore row vector `[1 3 2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[~,sorted_inds] = sort(M,2);
```

will do.

Comment: The problem was not stated specifically enough. When row entries are of same magnitude they should have the same index/ranking:

M =
     40    45    68
     50    65    65
     60    55    48
     57    57    44    
                      ,

should give:

O =

     1     2     3
     1     2     2
     2     2     1
     2     3     1
                       .

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the second output of the regular `sort` function:

```
[~,I] = sort(M,2)
```

This syntax supresses the actual sorted matrix `Msorted`, and returns the indices `I` such that

```
for j = 1:n, Msorted(j,:) = M(I(j,:),j); end
```

Type `doc sort` for more information.

Comment: How is this answer different from EmreA's?

Comment: @EitanT It contains more background :) Moreover, I started editing it when there were no answers yet

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: to rep-whore effectively post a minimal correct (enough) answer then edit it :-)

Comment: The problem was not stated specifically enough. When row entries are of same magnitude they should have the same index/ranking:

M =
     40    45    68
     50    65    65
     60    55    48
     57    57    44    
                      ,

should give:

O =

     1     2     3
     1     2     2
     2     2     1
     2     3     1
                       .

any ideas?